# How to get result from Pool.starmap_async()?

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, starmap

I have program which computes the index of array*value and returns a string. I use `.starmap_async()` because I must pass two arguments to my async function. The program looks as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

def go_async(self, index, value) :
        return str(index * int(value))

def log_result(self, result):
        print("Succesfully get callback! With result: ", result)

def main() :
    array = [1,3,4,5,6,7]
    pool = mp.Pool() 
    res = pool.starmap_async(go_async, enumerate(array), callback = log_result)        
    print("Final result: ", res)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    freeze_support()
    main()
```

I would like to get a result as an array of str:

```
res = ['0', '3', '8', '15', '24', '35']
```

but I have only result:

> Final result: multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at
>   0x000001F7C10E51D0

How to correctly get value from `.starmap_async()`?
Moreover, callback does not raise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pool's async-methods return objects which are conceptually ["explicit futures"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises#Implicit_vs._explicit), you need to call `.get()` to await and receive the actual result.
So `res.get()` will give you your result. You also need to remove `self` from your functions, since you are not passing an instance along your starmap-call. This currently leads to an exception within your target function and that's also the reason why your callback doesn't fire.

Comment: Cool, It's a solution for me.